# Device identifier in iOS safari user agent?

Tags: ios, iis, safari, device, user-agent

This list - http://enterpriseios.com/wiki/Complete_List_of_iOS_User_Agent_Strings - which I really like shows that safari user agent string tells us information bywhich we can identify a particular device, which is great.

My problem is when I check my user agent string on my iPhone 4 (at myhttp.info for example), I can see only "iPhone; iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X" and stuff in the user agent string and some other version number of the softwares (!), but no anything about the device.

I really want to see something like "Apple-iPhone3C1/1001.523", but I cant.

Can somebody explain me why is this happening? Is it something about iOS version? Or service provider? Or the actual device?

What is your user agent when browsing on the device? Can you see the device identifiers as we can see in the list mentioned?

Comment: Seems this is something that IIS provides - http://www.onesimplescript.com/2011/11/reporting-on-apple-ios-activesync.html

Comment: How to retrieve this variable in code at runtime? I really need this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of identifying the model of newer iOS devices through the User Agent string - **at least not in Mobile Safari**. Unfortunately, that's by design.

My iPad 3rd generation has the user agent `Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A523 Safari/8536.25`.

Other Apps with Web View might provide the information that you need. Facebook, for example, adds `iPad 3` to my User Agent string. However, you can't rely on that, since the grand majority of users browse on Mobile Safari.

### On a side note...

Apple has been very secretive on model identification ever since an analytics company went against their ToS and released version information of prototype iPads and iPhones they wanted to be kept secret at the time. See: [Steve Jobs Angry at Analytics Firms Tracking Apple Devices](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Steve-Jobs-Angry-at-Analytics-Firms-Tracking-its-Devices-143714.shtml).